# HTML List vertical align?

Tags: html, css

HTML List bullet jump to second line when it's line brake.

For expmple:

```
<ul>
    <li>First list</li>
    <li>Second list continue to second line.</li>
</ul>
```

- First list

  Second list continue to
- second line.

How do I make the second list bullet to show up, using CSS?

NOTE: This is only happen when there is not enough space. For example when I view this on my iPhone it's like this. But on my PC looks normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay adding some extra markup, your best bet is to try to utilize the *vertical-align* property.

```
<ul>
    <li><em></em><span>First list</span></li>
    <li><em></em><span>Second list continue to second line.</span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li em { 
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
li span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jB9Ad/

Answer (score 0):

From what I have collected of your Question... You want something along the lines of displaying another "INDENTED" Unordered/Ordered List within that list... Well without using Line Breaks or CSS you could do this...

```
<ul>
   <li>This is an item within the parent List.
      <ul>
         <li>This is a child list item, and the beginning of a new list.</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>This is the second item within the parent list</li>
 </ul>
```

That should help! :)

Comment: Well maybe my question is not clear, What's happening is <li> is auto wrapping according to screen size which not actually a line brake. Because of that auto wrapped <li> bullet shows on the second line!

Comment: @HardCode: Apply the display: block; CSS Property to both the list items and the sub-list items so like this.

ul li {
display: block;
}
ul li ul {
display: block;
}
ul li ul li {
display: block;
}

Answer (score 0):

if all you care about is iPhone or WebKit set your li's to overflow:ellipsis; firefox nightlies may support it, but i know ff hasn't had it for a bit.

Comment: because im an idiot; that's text-overflow:ellipsis  ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Comment: well, tried with the text-overflow and still have the same issue.

Comment: dude, did you even look @ that link? text-overflow:ellipsis has been supported by WebKit for a long time coming. here is a demo in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/9j6pR/1/

Comment: Well, I think you didn't understand my question. Look at Wex answer he solved it. I need to show bullets and I don't want to hide overflowed text. Thank you for your support!